# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connection 10'

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

```py
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
__author__ = 'abin'

import stomp
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    # filename='/home/abin/local/tools/activemq-consumer.log',
                    # filename='/home/abin/local/tools/extranet-consumer.log',
                    filename='activemq-monitor.log',
                    filemode='a')

class MyListener(object):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        logging.error('received an error %s' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        logging.info('received a message %s' % message)

######dev-platform####
conn = stomp.Connection10([('152.30.11.11',61613),('152.30.11.12',61613),('152.30.11.13',61613)])


conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()
conn.connect()

conn.subscribe(destination='heart.beat', id=1, ack='auto')

time.sleep(1)
conn.disconnect()
```

When I connect ActiveMQ by STOMP, it is working in CentOS (CentOS release 6.7 (Final)) and it is not working in Redhat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)). I do not know why?

This Python file is working by crontab's schedule in Linux.

I do this by STOMP plugins, the following is plugin:

http://blog.csdn.net/varyall/article/details/50252243

The error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/work/local/tools/activemq-consumer.py", line 27, in 
>       conn = stomp.Connection10([('152.30.11.11',61613),('152.30.11.12',61613),('152.30.11.13',61613)])
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connection10'

Comment: the problem is solved，if the stomp plugins store in the other folder that the python file is working.    now they are in the same folder.